# issue when creating SSH using ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “your@email.com” in git it gives “Too many arguments” error

Tags: ssh

I try to create SSH for using BitBucket with TortoisGit
I have typing the command for create the SSH (gitash) and get "Too many arguments" error.

the following is the output.
Thanks :)

```
     Yoav@Yoav-PC MINGW32 ~ $ ssh-keygen –t rsa –C "myEmail@gmail.com" 
Too many arguments. usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -l [-v] [-E fingerprint_hash] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -D pkcs11
       ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
       ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
       ssh-keygen -G output_file [-v] [-b bits] [-M memory] [-S start_point]
       ssh-keygen -T output_file -f input_file [-v] [-a rounds] [-J num_lines]
                  [-j start_line] [-K checkpt] [-W generator]
       ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-n principals]
                  [-O option] [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
       ssh-keygen -L [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -A
       ssh-keygen -k -f krl_file [-u] [-s ca_public] [-z version_number]
                  file ...
       ssh-keygen -Q -f krl_file file ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong dash symbol "`–`" in arguments; options are started with "`-`" (minus sign, ASCII code 0x2D). Here follows the same command with correct characters:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myEmail@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
...
```

Comment: This could happen when copying-and-pasting commands from a browser to the terminal.